# Why do I need to use “localhost” to connect to Docker MySQL DB on Windows?

Tags: windows, mysql, docker

I'm currently in the process of learning Docker (using it on Windows and Linux) and there is one thing I cannot understand and I think it is better explained with a example.

I run a MySQL container expose ports and then I connect to it via MySQL client such as MySQL Workbench. On Linux/Ubuntu I am able to connect to the DB running inside a container via its IP address, which I obtain by running:

```
docker inspect CONTAINER_NAME
```

This makes perfect sense to me, this is how I would connect to a database running on a server.

However, on Windows this approach doesn't work. I actually have to connect to `localhost` instead of container's IP. I understand that this has something to do with the fact that on Windows containers are running inside a Linux VM but in this case I should be using VM's IP address to connect to it.

Could someone explain to me why this works the way it works? I struggle to understand it (I'm still a junior developer) and I would rather understand how it works than just memorize commands/IPs for different OS.

Comment: If I try to connect using container's IP, it just saying it couldn't connect to given IP address: 10:19:43 Could not connect, server may not be running. Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.2' (10060)